# Is there a code for Ewald Summation for Dipoles?

Tags: electrostatics, computational-physics, dipole, molecular-dynamics, point-particles

Does anybody know if there exists a code that calculates the potential energy for a system with both point charges and point dipoles using Ewald summation?

This would be a great help to my Master thesis.

I appreciate all contributions, this includes any suggestion to good codes that are only for point charges (but can easily be extended to dipoles).

Comment: If you haven't already gotten an answer (or you have and want to post it somewhere), you might want to try the new [Materials Modeling SE](https://materials.stackexchange.com/#)

Comment: There is also an "ewald-summation" tag on the Materials Modeling Stack Exchange.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions. I have not seen any open-source codes that considers both point-charges and point dipoles and have therefore had to work around the issue in my master thesis. I'll definitely check out the Materials Modeling SE for future works.

Answer (score 1):

You probably don't need this code anymore, but I figured someone else might, so I put it like this [Ewald sum code for Kspace](https://github.com/zhaodazhuang/fenxiang-/tree/main/Ewald%20Sum%20code). Any other questions about Ewald Sum feel free to ask me.